# jQuery selector to get form by name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<form name="frmSave">...</form>
```

Just to know, I am **not able** to modify the HTML in order to add an `id` or something else.

This is what I tried to get the `form` element by it's name:

```
var frm = $('form[name="frmSave"]');

console.log(frm);
```

*(but I believe the above code will try to get a children element with the `frmSave` name inside the `form` which is not what I need).*

**How can I achieve this, is it possible to get the `form` by just the `name` and using a selector?**

---

### Update:

I was doing the wrong way in my original code (I was using a space aka "combinator" in the selector) and not in the code snippet from here so jQuery was trying to get any children element with the name needed and I was asking myself what was wrong since nothing was returned.

The accepted answer gives a better explanation about this so a little space could change everything - I will sleep properly next time :-)

Comment: Are you sure there are no other JS errors on the page stopping this from executing? Check the console logs.

Comment: I guess it was correct but for some reason it prints `null` at console, that's why I asked, maybe other thing could be the problem but I will check everything again.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`$('form[name="frmSave"]')` is correct. You mentioned you thought this would get all children with the name `frmsave` inside the form; this would only happen if there was a space or other combinator between the form and the selector, eg: `$('form [name="frmSave"]');`

`$('form[name="frmSave"]')` literally means *find all forms with the name `frmSave`*, because there is no combinator involved.

Answer (score 11):

```
    // this will give all the forms on the page.

    $('form')

   // If you know the name of form then.

    $('form[name="myFormName"]')

  //  If you don't know know the name but the position (starts with 0)

    $('form:eq(1)')  // 2nd form will be fetched.
```

Comment: I just had one form on the page and i use `$('form')` and it worked

Comment: it will return all the form, and there is only one form.

Answer (score 6):

You have no combinator (space, `>`, `+`...) so no children will get involved, ever.

However, you could avoid the need for jQuery by using an `ID` and `getElementById`, or you could use the old `getElementsByName("frmSave")[0]` or the even older `document.forms['frmSave']`. jQuery is unnecessary here.

Comment: `document.querySelector("form[name='frmSave']")` would work too, but only in newer browsers.

Comment: I know it is unnecessary but I am working with other code that requires jQuery that's why I am using it for this, thanks for your explanation btw +1.

Comment: Nothing "requires" jQuery, not really ;) I'm happily using accordions, sliders, tooltips and modal dialogs with hand-written vanilla JS, and I feel much more accomplished for it.

Answer (score 2):

For detecting if the form is present, I'm using

```
if($('form[name="frmSave"]').length > 0) {
    //do something
}
```